# Running MPI on LAN Cluster with different usernames

Tags: mpi, host

I have two machines with different usernames: assume `user1@master` and `user2@slave`. I would like to run a MPI job on the two machines, but I have been unsuccessful until now. I have successfully setup passwordless ssh between the two machines. Both machines have the same version of OpenMPI and both machines have the `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` setup correspondingly.

The path for openmpi on each machine is `/home/$USER/.openmpi` and the program I want to run is inside `~/folder`

My /etc/hosts file on both machines:

```
master x.x.x.110
slave  x.x.x.111
```

My /.ssh/config file on `user1@master`:

```
Host slave
User user2
```

I then execute the command on `user1@master` while inside `~/folder` as follows:

```
$ mpiexec -n 1 ./program : -np 1 -host slave -wdir /home/user2/folder ./program
```

I get the following error:

```
bash: orted: command not found
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ORTE was unable to reliably start one or more daemons.
This usually is caused by:

* not finding the required libraries and/or binaries on
  one or more nodes. Please check your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH
  settings, or configure OMPI with --enable-orterun-prefix-by-default

* lack of authority to execute on one or more specified nodes.
  Please verify your allocation and authorities.

* the inability to write startup files into /tmp (--tmpdir/orte_tmpdir_base).
  Please check with your sys admin to determine the correct location to use.

*  compilation of the orted with dynamic libraries when static are required
  (e.g., on Cray). Please check your configure cmd line and consider using
  one of the contrib/platform definitions for your system type.

* an inability to create a connection back to mpirun due to a
  lack of common network interfaces and/or no route found between
  them. Please check network connectivity (including firewalls
  and network routing requirements).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Edits**

If I use a hostfile with contents:

```
localhost
user2@slave
```

along with the `--mca` argument I get the following error:

```
$ mpirun --mca plm_base_verbose 10 -n 5 --hostfile hosts.txt ./program
[user:29277] mca: base: components_register: registering framework plm components
[user:29277] mca: base: components_register: found loaded component slurm
[user:29277] mca: base: components_register: component slurm register function successful
[user:29277] mca: base: components_register: found loaded component isolated
[user:29277] mca: base: components_register: component isolated has no register or open function
[user:29277] mca: base: components_register: found loaded component rsh
[user:29277] mca: base: components_register: component rsh register function successful
[user:29277] mca: base: components_open: opening plm components
[user:29277] mca: base: components_open: found loaded component slurm
[user:29277] mca: base: components_open: component slurm open function successful
[user:29277] mca: base: components_open: found loaded component isolated
[user:29277] mca: base: components_open: component isolated open function successful
[user:29277] mca: base: components_open: found loaded component rsh
[user:29277] mca: base: components_open: component rsh open function successful
[user:29277] mca:base:select: Auto-selecting plm components
[user:29277] mca:base:select:(  plm) Querying component [slurm]
[user:29277] mca:base:select:(  plm) Querying component [isolated]
[user:29277] mca:base:select:(  plm) Query of component [isolated] set priority to 0
[user:29277] mca:base:select:(  plm) Querying component [rsh]
[user:29277] mca:base:select:(  plm) Query of component [rsh] set priority to 10
[user:29277] mca:base:select:(  plm) Selected component [rsh]
[user:29277] mca: base: close: component slurm closed
[user:29277] mca: base: close: unloading component slurm
[user:29277] mca: base: close: component isolated closed
[user:29277] mca: base: close: unloading component isolated
[user:29277] *** Process received signal ***
[user:29277] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[user:29277] Signal code:  (128)
[user:29277] Failing at address: (nil)
[user:29277] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x3ef20)[0x7f4226242f20]
[user:29277] [ 1] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_malloc+0x197)[0x7f422629b207]
[user:29277] [ 2] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__nss_lookup_function+0x10a)[0x7f422634d06a]
[user:29277] [ 3] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__nss_lookup+0x3d)[0x7f422634d19d]
[user:29277] [ 4] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(getpwuid_r+0x2f3)[0x7f42262e7ee3]
[user:29277] [ 5] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(getpwuid+0x98)[0x7f42262e7498]
[user:29277] [ 6] /home/.openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_plm_rsh.so(+0x477d)[0x7f422356977d]
[user:29277] [ 7] /home/.openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_plm_rsh.so(+0x67a7)[0x7f422356b7a7]
[user:29277] [ 8] /home/.openmpi/lib/libopen-pal.so.40(opal_libevent2022_event_base_loop+0xdc9)[0x7f4226675749]
[user:29277] [ 9] mpirun(+0x1262)[0x563fde915262]
[user:29277] [10] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7)[0x7f4226225b97]
[user:29277] [11] mpirun(+0xe7a)[0x563fde914e7a]
[user:29277] *** End of error message ***
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I do not get any ssh orte info as asked but maybe becuase i am mistyping the `--mca` command?

Comment: it seems you are mixing `mpiexec` syntax (e.g. `-n 1`) with `mpirun` syntax (e.g. `-np 1`). try to use the full path to `mpirun` (e.g. `/opt/openmpi-3.1.3/bin/mpirun` and see whether it helps. an other option is to `configure --with-enable-mpirun-prefix-by-default` and rebuild/install Open MPI.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I tried doing what you suggested but that did not solve the problem. To try and skip over the problem i reinstalled OpenMPI on both machines in the same directory: `/home/.openmpi` and then setting up a nfs shared folder with the code. This also did not change my output error and I have exactly the same thing as before.

Comment: did you `configure --enable-mpirun-prefix-by-default` ? if you `mpirun --mca plm_base_verbose 10 ...` it should print the `ssh ... orted ...` command line that is ran under the hood, and you can try to run it manually (could be a permission issue on the Open MPI libs). Have you tried using a hostfile using the `user@host` syntax instead of tweaking your `.ssh/config` ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet yes, i tried with both `--enable-mpirun-prefix-by-default` and `--enable-orterun-prefix-by-default` (as suggested in the error message) with no change in the output. for `--mca` command, see edits. I tried using a hostfile too. Thanks for all your suggestions! The problem still exists but atleast I'm learning quite a bit!

Comment: this is the log of a `mpirun` crash and that should never happen ! can you run `mpirun --mca plm_base_verbose 10 ...` without the hostfile (and relying on your ssh config instead) ?